# Sufficient condition for two matrices to satisfy braid relation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have two matrices $A$ and $B$. Is there '*simple*' condition that implies $A$ and $B$ satisfy a braid relation of some length? i.e.

$ABABA\ldots = BABAB\ldots$

where both sides are of equal length.

- By '*simple*' I was thinking in terms of the eigen-structure of $A$ and $B$. I would like to be able to automate the checking of this condition in *e.g.* Maple.
- I'm particularly interested in matrices in $SU(n,1)$, but results for
  other matrix groups are welcome.
- A negative condition would also be useful, i.e. if $A$ and $B$ have some property then they do not satisfy a braid relation of any length.

Comment: Does the braid relation necessarily involve an even number of terms (so that $\{A,B\} \in \mbox{ braidPairs } \wedge s\in \Bbb R \implies  \{sA,B\} \in \mbox{ braidPairs }$)?

Comment: The braid relations can be any length.

Answer (score 1):

First, if the length is odd, say, $F:=ABABA=BABAB$ then $ABABABABAB=F^2=BABABABABA$. So if the braid relation is satisfied for some odd length then it is satisfied for some even length. Therefore we can solve for even lengths only.

Now let's say there exists a natural number $m$ such that $C:=(AB)^m=(BA)^m$. We have that if $C:=ABABAB=BABABA$ then
$$AABABAB=ABABABA$$
$$AABABAB=BABABAA$$
$$AC=CA$$

Similarly,
$$BABABAB=BBABABA$$
$$ABABABB=BBABABA$$
$$CB=BC$$

By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289559/ab-ba-ac-ca-we-need-to-show-bc-cb), if $C$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues then $AB=BA$. Check if $BA=AB$. This is a sufficient condition. It is also necessary if $C$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. How can we check that? Look at the eigenvalues of $AB$ (which are the same as the eigenvalues of $BA$). Since $A$ and $B$ are unitary, $AB$ is unitary. So its eigenvalues are on the unit circle. They are equivalent if there exists a natural number $m$ such that $\mathrm{e}^{im\theta}=\mathrm{e}^{im\phi}$. This happens iff there exists an integer $k$ such that $m(\theta-\phi)=2\pi k \iff \theta-\phi=q\pi$ for some rational number $q$. If $AB$ has no equivalent eigenvalues then $(AB)^m$ has distinct eigenvalues (no matter what $m$). In this case, a necessary (and sufficient) condition would be that $AB=BA$ which is easy to check.